easy way to code the sensor for jetson nano
how can I code a specific sensor's working if I connect it directly to the jetson nano board?
Is there any particular IDE to do that?
Is it okay to use breadboard in this process?
I was expecting a specific IDE to code over the sensor connected to the Jetson Nano.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
